# How can I enumerate references?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, bibliographies, numbering

I tried to write a paper for practicing, but I encountered some problems. Namely, Why don't I see references on the table of contents and why the references chapter has number two instead of three and why there are smaller space between the number 2 and the letter R? Is it easy to fix those things?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{euscript}
\linespread{1.6}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\card}{\operatorname{card}}
\newcommand{\Hom}{\operatorname{Hom}}
\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{nota}{Notation}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{exam}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem{corp}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{theo}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{note}{Note}[section]
\renewcommand{\refname}{\thesection\ References}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\thesection\ References}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Abstract}
\section{Chapter first}
\subsection{Subchapter1}
something
\subsection{Subchapter2}
Now we can conclude the following~\cite{author}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{author} Author, Title, Journal
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forget the renaming of `\refname` and simply use »[tocbibind](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind)«.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \bigskip
  \begin{thebibliography}{9}
    \bibitem{key} Author, Title, Journal
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right! I'm not sure what I did before when I ran your example and somehow didn't generate a numbered section for the References. I'll delete my initial comment!

Comment: As @Mico, this is the first thing I've tried... But I don't know what I did wrong, I didn't get it in the ToC, so I've thought it didn't work with `thebibliography`... +1.

Comment: @karlkoeller: I can't say what you did wrong. Perhaps you just needed one more compiler run. This method has always worked fine for me.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, you are talking about "sections" and not "chapters". In fact, the `article` class does not support chapters.

To get the right name and spacing for the "References" section, replace

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{\thesection\ References}
```

with

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{\thesection\hspace{1em}References}
```

To get the right numbering, you have to issue the command

```
\refstepcounter{section}
```

before your `thebibliography` environment.

Finally, to add the information in the ToC, you have to issue the command

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}
```

Complete code (I removed the unneeded parts):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{euscript}
\linespread{1.6}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\refname}{\thesection\hspace{1em}References}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Abstract}
\section{Chapter first}
\subsection{Subchapter1}
something
\subsection{Subchapter2}
Now we can conclude the following~\cite{author}

\refstepcounter{section}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}
\bibitem{author} Author, Title, Journal
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: One can also type `\quad` instead of `\hspace{1em}`. :-)